# How to compare the data in two Excel sheets

Tags: excel

How to compare the data between two Excel sheets? I have two Excel sheets with one come column but the number of columns is different. I want check if particular data in sheet one exists in sheet 2 if they exists I need to display true or false in a separate column.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

suppose u have two sheet sheet1, sheet2

Write on sheet1 if u want to compare data on (A1 Cell of sheet1) with (B1 Cell of sheet2)

**= IF(A1=Sheet2!B1,"TRUE","FALSE")**

Answer (score 1):

Try this command in a paralel column:

```
=EXACT(cell1,cell2)
```

it will display boolean variable (true ,false).